# Why do I get [firestore/permission-denied] even though I allow all read and writes?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, expo, react-native-firebase

I've got a React Native project set up with React Native Firebase, and I am using Expo. In my firestore.rules the following configuration is defined.

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

But regardless, when I try adding an item with:

```
export const addGearItem = async (
  data: IGearItem,
  user: FirebaseAuthTypes.User
): Promise<IGearItem> => {
  const serializedData = serializeGearItem(data);

  await firestore()
    .collection(COLLECTIONS.GEAR)
    .doc(user.uid)
    .collection(COLLECTIONS.ITEMS)
    .add(serializedData);

  return data;
};
```

I get the error

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 3):
Error: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
NativeFirebaseError: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
    at get (http://10.134.184.52:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:244380:52)
    at ?anon_0_ (http://10.134.184.52:8081/src/services/firestoreService.bundle//&platform=ios&hot=false&lazy=true&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=true&runModule=false&shallow=true:46:115)
    at next (native)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://10.134.184.52:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:5991:26)
    at _next (http://10.134.184.52:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:6010:29)
    at anonymous (http://10.134.184.52:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:6015:14)
    at tryCallTwo (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:61:9)
    at doResolve (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:216:25)
    at Promise (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:82:14)
    at anonymous (http://10.134.184.52:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:6007:25)
    at apply (native)
```

This is true for both when I'm running the emulator, and when I'm not (e.g. pushing to production).

**Update**
I've tried just running a simple query to firestore and get the following error, so it's possible that there's an underlying issue. What that is, I have no idea.

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: [firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff.
NativeFirebaseError: [firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff.
    at get (http://10.134.184.52:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:243038:50)
    at ?anon_0_ (http://10.134.184.52:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:255640:86)
    at next (native)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://10.134.184.52:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:5991:26)
    at _next (http://10.134.184.52:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:6010:29)
    at anonymous (http://10.134.184.52:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:6015:14)
    at tryCallTwo (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:61:9)
    at doResolve (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:216:25)
    at Promise (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:82:14)
    at anonymous (http://10.134.184.52:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:6007:25)
    at apply (native)
```

Comment: I would try to double check the config section, and make sure the initialization passes through without issue.  I looked at the rule it looks good at first glance.